# Javascript - get very big number as string containing all digits

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I've consulted the [mozilla developer reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) for `Number.prototype.toFixed`, and it lead me to believe that if I have a very big number showing in scientific notation, I can do this to see the whole number:

```
myBigNum.toFixed(2);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. For example, if I want to see all 308 glorious digits of `Number.MAX_VALUE`, the following *still shows me a string in scientific notation*:

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE.toFixed(2));
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE.toFixed(2).constructor.name);
```

**How can I get a string showing all the digits of an arbitrary, very large (or very small) number in javascript?**

(Note: I realize that many trailing digits may exhibit float-point-funkiness!)

Comment: JavaScript numbers only have about 17 digits of precision. It can't represent a 300-digit number exactly.

Comment: Have you considered [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)?

Comment: Here is a function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `toLocaleString` method (with some options, if needed):

```js
const s = Number.MAX_VALUE.toLocaleString(undefined, {
  style: 'decimal',
  useGrouping: false //Flip to true if you want to include commas
});

console.log(s)
```