# How to solve unknown in math.js?

Tags: javascript, mathjs

I find math.js Don't have solve function for an unknown equation like the following equation
`var eq = (2.75501+x*0.0013016)+(1.89908+x*-0.0006573)-5 = 0`

and when I try to simplify

```
var simplify_eq =math.rationalize("(2.75501+x*0.0013016)+(1.89908+x*-0.0006573)-5");
```

it gives me:
6.443e-4 * x - 0.34590999999999994
which e I don't want 
I want the number to be 0.00006443
I have tried library like algebra.js but it cannot solve with e like above

Comment: `6.443e-4` **is** `0.00006443`. It's two ways of writing exactly the same value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: For the second part of your question, you could multiply it by 10m round it then divide by 10m... `answer = Math.round(answer * 10000000) / 10000000`