# Large number values shows in exponential format Kendo jquery Tree List

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I am using kendo JQuery Tree List. When very large number is coming from response then its displaying in Exponential format. I believe this is java script limitation for numbers having more than 15 digits.

Is there any workaround for the same. I would like to display the number as it is and should respect format

Dojo for the same: https://dojo.telerik.com/@amitdwivedi/uzecuDep

Kendo version for jquery :
 "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2018.2.530",

Comment: Maybe try some of these methods:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Number supports integers till 2^53 - 1.
If you want a bigger number than that please try  BigInt .
You can write  a very big number like this.

```
const theBiggestInt = BigInt(9007199254740991324324324324324);
```

More more you can refer this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt