# prevent scientific notation ins angular8 input value

Tags: angular

I have input text field in angular, that converts large value to 5.5E9.
When the value is supposed to show - 5500000000

Here is the input field:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="sck" 
                   name="cap1" [pattern]="checkPattern"
                    placeholder="cap" type="text"
                    class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"  #uname="ngModel">
```

Here is the check pattern in the ts

```
this.checkPattern = "^[0-9]*$";
```

Please how do I prevent the exponential value in the input field

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't add `ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid` css classes. Angular adds it itself. You may also use a formControl instead.

Comment: why does angular adds it and angularjs does not add it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Add number pipe to `[(ngModel)]` in a following way:

```
<input 
  [ngModel]="sck | number:'1.0-8'" 
  (ngModelChange)="sck = $event"                 
  name="cap1" 
  [pattern]="checkPattern"
  placeholder="cap" 
  type="text"
  #uname="ngModel" />
```

`[ngModel]` will format it fine and `(ngModelChange)` will take care of assignment.