# How to convert exponential value to decimal in nodejs?

Tags: api, numbers, decimal, converters, exponential

I am receiving data as,

```
{
    "balance": 1e+22
}
```

and I want it as,

```
{
    "balance": 10000000000000000000000 
}
```

What should I do so that I get proper response value in Node APIs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

Solution found: [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Code which worked as a perfect solution: `BigInt(n).toString();`

Comment: This answer was already mentioned as a duplicate.