# Multiplication method of very long decimal data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I got a data from server like this object.

```
[
  {
    rawTime: '2021-12-01T14:58:21.000+0000',
    score: 5.4928278748
  },
  {
    rawTime: '2021-12-01T14:58:21.000+0000',
    score: 7.4928278748
  }
]
```

I want to make this object like this. Multiple all score value data with 10

```
[
  {
    rawTime: '2021-12-01T14:58:21.000+0000',
    score: 54.928278748
  },
  {
    rawTime: '2021-12-01T14:58:21.000+0000',
    score: 74.928278748
  }
]
```

And I thought it can use 'map' with this.

```
let processedData = itemData.data.identicalList;
processedData.forEach(function(element,index,_array){
   _array[index].score = element.score.toPrecision(5)*10;
})
```

And it actually works, but some values are not multiplying. And I don't know why.
Numbers that are not multiplied look like this.
How can I solve this?

`7.3314e+25 %`

[image]

Comment: In `7.3314e+25` e+25 means you have to do `7.3314 * 10^(+25)`. Which mean it's too large number (before the decimal point).

Comment: You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript) helpful.