# What type to use for big numbers?

Tags: near-sdk-rs

Reference to my smart contract file: https://github.com/amirsaranBIH/nearkick/blob/13-create-logic-for-users-to-remove-themselves-from-projects/contract/src/lib.rs

My main state struct looks like this:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug)]
#[serde(crate = "near_sdk::serde")]
pub struct Project {
    pub id: u64,
    pub owner: AccountId,
    pub name: String,
    pub description: String,
    pub supporters: HashMap<AccountId, Supporter>,
    pub balance: Balance,
    pub goal: Balance,
    pub end_time: u64,
    pub status: ProjectStatus,
    pub plan: SupporterPlans,
    pub level_amounts: HashMap<SupporterType, Balance>,
    pub images: Vec<String>,
}
```

The `Balance` type is just `pub type Balance = u128;`.

I will use the `pub fn add_project` method to explain my problem.

```rust
pub fn add_project(
        &mut self,
        goal: U128,
        name: String,
        description: String,
        plan: SupporterPlans,
        end_time: u64,
        cadence: String,
        basic_supporter_amount: U128,
        intermediate_supporter_amount: U128,
        advanced_supporter_amount: U128,
        images: Vec<String>,
    ) -> u64
```

Because JavaScript has poor big number support I had to use `U128` for my `pub fn add_project` parameters (`goal: U128`, `basic_supporter_amount: U128`, `intermediate_supporter_amount: U128` and `advanced_supporter_amount: U128`).

For example:
In JavaScript the number `5000000000000000000000000` would be transformed into `5e+24` and be sent over as a parameter of my smart contract call. This would cause the smart contract to panic.

Right now I am just sending big numbers as strings and it works. The values are stored in state.

======================

The problem is with my view methods. The `balance: Balance`, `goal: Balance` and `level_amounts: HashMap<SupporterType, Balance>` properties are `u128`.

When returned into my JavaScript code and turned into an Object the numbers are just `5e+24`.

It is also like this when called trough the near-cli (Here is an example: `near view dev-1657316029595-71822829120195 get_all_projects '{}'`)

Some solutions that I have thought of:

- Use `U128` instead of `Balance` for my state properties. -> This is not that great because I would have to convert from `U128` to `u128` every time I had to do some arithmetic operations.
- Create a format function in JavaScript that will convert numbers from `5e+24` to `"5000000000000000000000000"`. -> Some conversion methods that I have found are not precise. (Tried these: [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript))

Is there a way to use `Balance/u128` types for my number properties and to have "string-like" numbers in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the best way to go is actually to use the `U128` type from `near-sdk-rs` that will return large numbers as strings to your client side app, saving you from writing logic for handling numbers like `5e+24`.

Comment: How to make  Rust in NEAR-SDK convert `U128` into a string **with all the 24 zeros**? In my smart contract it'll return  `Balance` as `5e+24` which I then won't be able to convert into integer properly on the client side.